# Auto-increment field in OpenOffice Writer when printing

Tags: printing, openoffice-writer

I'm trying to print a set of empty bills with OpenOffice Writer. I have an empty template, and what I would like to do is print a different bill number with every copy.

The idea would be something like this:

1. Select Print
2. Choose start and stop increments
3. Get printed copies with a different value in each

I've tried to look into fields, but from what I'm getting the only way I could do this is to setup an OpenOffice Database with as many entries as I wish to print and use it a data source for my file when printing.

Is there an easier way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a csv file as a 'database' and generate your forms using mail merge. Generate a text file

```
number
1
2
3
... max number
```

and save it, e.g. mynums.csv.
Add a field to your form and link it to the number field of the mynumbs.csv file (insert/field/other, choose database type and navigate to the mynumbs.csv file, then choose the number field as the data source).

When you print the document, choose to print a form letter. You can then choose the start and stop values in the dialog box that appears. You can print directly to paper, but also to a file or files.

Comment: This is indeed what I ended up doing, generating the csv from bash. I still find it too bad to have to use a separate data file, so I'll wait to see if someone else has another option :-)